# clisp 2.49: asdf cannot find asd

Tags: common-lisp, asdf

My setup is:
Windows Vista
clisp 2.49

I run clisp and load asdf without any problems. 
I push a directory pathname into `asdf:*central-registry*` and copy a shortcut of cl-ppcre.asd into the directory. Then I try to load-op it with `(asdf:oos 'asdf:load-op 'cl-ppcre)` and i get a response that "component 'cl-ppcre' not found". Any suggestions? Asdf is version 2.010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution:

http://bc.tech.coop/blog/041113.html

In a few words, the problem is that ASDF doesn't like Windows' shortcuts, it wants soft links and the two are not the same. The link describes 2-3 ways of dealing with this.

Comment: the link is now broken, which is why you should summarize answers in links as well as providing them...

Answer (score 1):

ASDF is *meant* to support shortcuts. If the support is buggy, please contribute a fix.

That said, with ASDF2, the recommended way of configuring ASDF is to put your code in one of the standard locations, and/or to add entries to the source-registry.

Comment: To be honest, I read the recommended method in ASDF2 manual and I found it way too complicated in comparison with just pushing shortcuts  into central-registry. Maybe the manual makes it seem complicated or I was too tired to try and understand it, but the fact that it suggests a separate folder with a specific unix-like naming or creating windows registry keys was enough to make me stop reading and fall back to old method.

Comment: i had the same experience. what is the standard location for user systems under windows? the one corresponding to "~/.local/share/common-lisp/source/" mentioned in the manual?

Comment: I dont know, I didnt bother finding out. I used old method. I do want to use the new one, but I always postpone it.

Comment: Even if you want to do the old method, you don't need to do the shortcuts, you can simply do something like this in your .sbclrc (or whatever init file): `(push "/path/to/my/library/" asdf:*central-registry*)`