# ASDF on Windows 7 cannot load the ASD file using CLISP or SBCL

Tags: windows, common-lisp, sbcl, clisp, asdf

On my Windows 7 `CLISP 2.49` and `SBCL-1.4.14` are installed and they work perfectly. `ASDF 3.3.1` is loaded  by the these lines on `.sbclrc` or `.clisprc`

```
(load "C:\\Users\\mayhem\\lisp\\asdf\\asdf.lisp")
(require :asdf)
(push "C:\\Users\\mayhem\\lisp\\systems\\" asdf:*central-registry*)
```

I'd like to load and use the `iterate` package/library using `ASDF` (not QuickLisp) so I've installed the [iterate](https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/iterate/iterate.git) into `C:\Users\mayhem\lisp\iterate` and on `CMD.exe`

```
> cd C:\Users\mayhem\lisp\systems
> junction.exe iterate.asd C:\Users\mayhem\lisp\iterate\iterate.asd
```

If I `(require 'iterate)` whether on REPL or in a file, I get

```
CLISP: *** - LOAD: A file with name ITERATE does not exist

SBCL:  ASDF could not load iterate because Error while trying to load definition for system iterate from pathname C:/Users/mayhem/lisp/systems/iterate.asd/: error opening #P"C:/Users/mayhem/lisp/systems/iterate.asd/": Access denied..
While evaluating the form starting at line 1, column 0
  of #P"C:/Users/mayhem/lisp/defsystem.lisp":
```

If I try to load the `iterate.asd` directly then I get
`EVAL: undefined function DEFSYSTEM`

How to fix the problem?

Update 1:
I've added `(push "C:\\Users\\mayhem\\lisp\\iterate\\" asdf:*central-registry*)` into `.sbclrc`. That is, I did the loading of iterate.asd without relying on soft links. When I entered `(require 'iterate)` on REPL it gave:

```
(require 'iterate)
ASDF could not load iterate because
Uneven number of components in source to destination mapping: "C:/".
....
(ASDF/OUTPUT-TRANSLATIONS:PARSE-OUTPUT-TRANSLATIONS-STRING "C:/" :LOCATION NIL)
   source: (ERROR
            (COMPATFMT
             "~@<Uneven number of components in source to destination mapping: ~3i~_~S~@:>")
            STRING)
```

I've added the same line to `.clisprc` and `CLISP` gave:
`*** - LOAD: A file with name ITERATE does not exist`

Update 2:
I've tried the setup above on Windows **XP** (i.e. by adding `(push "C:\\Documents and Settings\\mayhem\\lisp\\iterate\\" asdf:*central-registry*)` to CLISP init file and without using the junctioned/soft linked ASD files) and it did work! So the problem is limited to Windows **7**. I've just learnt that the ASDF don't play well with the Windows soft links. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249663/clisp-2-49-asdf-cannot-find-asd))

Comment: "Access denied" might be a clue for the problem, it's hard to know better here. But you cannot evaluate the `defsystem` form if you are not in the right package (asdf-user I think). In fact you should never need to evaluate it directly, even for debugging. What if you push directly `"C:\\Users\\mayhem\\lisp\\iterate\\"` into `asdf:*central-registry*`?

Comment: @coredump Thank you for the comment. I've just added an update to the question. The error message on `SBCL` has changed while the one on `CLISP` has remained more or less the same. From the error message on `SBCL` it looks like a Windows path problem, maybe.

Comment: I've added a second update. After I 've used the updated setup on Windows **XP**, the ASDF did work.

Comment: Great, I heard "mklink" is the recommend way on Windows instead of junction.exe, but I don't really have experience with this